# How to multiply arrays in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have two arrays

x = [a,b,c]
y = [5,6,7]

I want to calculate the product such that the result of x * y is
 x[0]* 5 + x[1] * 6 + x[2] * 7

Actually this is part of constraints equation that I have to form for optimization using scipy and pandas.

Also,

I have many numpy arrays that I created after reading a csv file. And I want to create my objective function on run time.
Here is the hard coded form of the objective function

```
def objFunc(x,sign=1.0) :
"""return sign*(sum(coeff[0:] *(wf[0:] + wv[0:] * decisionVars[0:])**power.values[0:]))"""
return sign* (( coeff.values[0]*(wf.values[0]+ wv.values[0] *x[0])**power.values[0] ) +
(coeff.values[1]*(wf.values[1]+ wv.values[1] *x[0])**power.values[1])+
(coeff.values[2]*(wf.values[2]+ wv.values[2] *x[0])**power.values[2]) +
(coeff.values[3]*(wf.values[3]+ wv.values[3] *x[0])**power.values[3]) +
(coeff.values[4]*(wf.values[4]+ wv.values[4] *x[0])**power.values[4] )+
(coeff.values[5]*(wf.values[5]+ wv.values[5] *x[0])**power.values[5]) +
(coeff.values[6]*(wf.values[6]+ wv.values[6] *x[1])**power.values[6]) +
(coeff.values[7]*(wf.values[7]+ wv.values[7] *x[1])**power.values[7]) +
(coeff.values[8]*(wf.values[8]+ wv.values[8] *x[1])**power.values[8]) +
(coeff.values[9]*(wf.values[9]+ wv.values[9] *x[2])**power.values[9]) +
(coeff.values[10]*(wf.values[10]+ wv.values[10] *x[2])**power.values[10]) +
(coeff.values[11]*(wf.values[11]+ wv.values[11] *x[2])**power.values[11]))
```

I used various ways to calculate it but to no avail.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('C:\Users\prashant.mudgal\Downloads\T1 - Copy.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('C:\Users\prashant.mudgal\Downloads\T2.csv')
decisionVars= df2['DV']
coeff = df2['coef']

"""subset for power"""
power = df2['p']
wf = df2['weight_f']
wv = df2['weight_v']

def objFunc(x,sign=1.0) :
return sign*(sum(coeff[0:] *(wf[0:] + wv[0:] * decisionVars[0:])**power.values[0:]))
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with pandas, but it seems that it should be pretty simple -- Something akin to `x * y`.  Do you have any code?

Comment: If you have two _arrays_, that's not pandas, it's just numpy, and the answer is `x * y`. If you have `DataFrame`s or something else that actually _is_ pandas, then you have to tell us what you have, and explain exactly what you mean by multiplying them, because they don't have `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. values.

Comment: Hi all,Yes I am trying to run optimization using scipy and pandas packages and its a hard nut to crack in absence of literature. I posted my original problem here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799201/scipy-and-pandas-package-optimization   . I have to define a constraint such that DV1 * historic_inv1 + DV2 * historic_inv2 + DV3 *historic_inv3 = 20000. DV1,DV2,DV3 are in DV column of T1.csv and historic investments are in hist_inv column of T1.csv. The link above has description of T1.csv and T2.csv

Answer (score -1):

This works out of the box:

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]], columns=list('ab'))

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7

In [11]: df.a * df.b
Out[11]: 
0     5
1    12
2    21
dtype: int64
```